# How to create an exception code (Arduino interface with python Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, pyserial

This is a python interface from Arduino:

When running my python interface sometimes I get this error:

> raise SerialException('device reports readiness to read but returned
>   no data (device disconnected or multiple access on
>   port?)')SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned
>   no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)

This is part of the code:

```
import serial
import time
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/cu.usbmodem1411", 9600, timeout=1)
....
....
def do_update():
   ...
   allitems=ser.readline(4)
   x, y = allitems.split()
   ...
   root.after(1000, do_update)
   ...
do_update()
root.mainloop()
```

So, I understand the problem is when there is not data transmission on a loop, so how can I tell the code to just show the last value if it finds this error message?

Comment: you can use try block to catch exception

Answer (score 0):

Just like Hackaholic pointed out:

use a try / except / else / finally block to catch this exception.
To learn more about it have a close look at the [documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions).

You can use sth. like:

```
    def do_update():
        global ser
        try:
            """
            A try block runs until __ANY__ exception is raised
            """
            # do your stuff like reading / parsing data over here
            allitems=ser.readline(4)
            x, y = allitems.split()
        except serial.SerialException:
            """
            An except block is entered when a exception occured, can be parameterized by the type of exception. Using *except  as ex* you can access the details of the exceptions inside your exception Block.
            """
            # do whatever you want to do if __this specific__ exception occurs
            print("Serial Exception caught!")
        else:
            print("Different Exception caught!")
        finally:
            """
            A finally branch of a try/except/else/finally block is done always after an exception has occured.
            """
            # continue calling it again __always__
            root.after(1000, do_update)
```